Is there a way to v-bind Components (while setting its prop) as prop of another component as shown below
<MyParentComponent :component-prop="MyChildComponent.ChildComponentProp.value = 'xyz'">
This is what I want to achieve. I want to provide MyParentComponent a child component as a prop.
But I also what to define the props of the child component before MyParentComponent uses it.
I read through docs and other questions on Stack but no resolve.

You can define the component-prop as an object with the following structure:
<parent-component :component-prop="{
  component: ChildComponent,
  props: ChildComponentProps
}" />

Then in parent component bind the props to the passed component:
<component :is="componentProp.component" v-bind="componentProp.props" />


I understand. I looked into this option. Currently it works for me but I was trying to find a more efficient way of doing this which is accessing providing the prop directly. Your answer is great though!
I can't up vote it until my reputation goes up ❤️
